# Updating occured error details into current database within undo'ed transaction

Tags: error-handling, transactions, progress-4gl

I have a simple database which contains few tables and also a table for runtime errors. The idea is to save all occurred runtime errors into this table. The following demonstrates my use-case:

**test1.p:**

```
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

/* Some code which throws error */
RUN errorThrowingProcedure.

/* Catch any errors */
CATCH oError AS Progress.Lang.Error:
    
    /* Write error to current database */
    DEF BUFFER Errors_B1 FOR Errors.
    CREATE Errors_B1.
    ASSIGN Errors_B1.DateTimeTz = NOW
           Errors_B1.ProgramName = PROGRAM-NAME(1)
           Errors_B1.Message     = oError:GetMessage(1).
    
    /* Rethrow error to upper level */
    UNDO, THROW oError.
END.
```

This doesn't work because of the error 'rethrow', which will `UNDO` the database changes.

I don't want to save the error to some `NO-UNDO` variables or `TEMP-TABLE`s and do the update later. I also don't want to spread this kind of error logic to multiple places depending on the ongoing transactions.

I was thinking about doing it the following way:

**test2.p:**

```
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

/* Some code which throws error */
RUN errorThrowingProcedure.

/* Catch any errors */
CATCH oError AS Progress.Lang.Error:
    
    DEF VAR cCommandLine AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
    DEF VAR cApplication AS CHAR NO-UNDO INIT "C:\Progress91E\bin\prowin32.exe".
    DEF VAR cDatabase    AS CHAR NO-UNDO INIT "MyDatabase".
    DEF VAR cParams      AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
    DEF VAR cProcedure   AS CHAR NO-UNDO INIT "C:\WRK91E\CreateError.p".

    /* Params: 'Errors.DateTimeTz', 'Errors.ProgramName' and 'Errors.Message' */
    cParams = SUBST("&1, &2, &3", NOW, PROGRAM-NAME(1), oError:GetMessage(1)).

    cCommandLine = SUBST('&1 &2 -param "&3" -b -p &4', cApplication, cDatabase, cParams, cProcedure).

    /* Write occured error to database */
    OS-COMMAND NO-WAIT NO-CONSOLE VALUE(cCommandLine) NO-ERROR.
    
    /* Rethrow error to upper level */
    UNDO, THROW oError.
END.
```

Is there's any other simpler way to achieve this?

I wouldn't want to rely on `OS-COMMAND` if there's another easier or more robust way to invoke a new progress client within the current client process. The code above is also platform specific. I'd like to make it work on all possible platforms..

Comment: 9.1e is ancient, do you still need it to work in that version

Comment: @carlverbiest No, solution for the latest Progress version would be best

Answer (score 1):

Launching another OpenEdge batch client seems expensive.

Do you have access to an OpenEdge AppServer? AppServer's don't share the transaction with the client.

How about logging to file?

Comment: The errors are currently logged to text files, but it's not enough.. `AppServer` is available when the codes are running at the server.  `REST` services are not yet used with the `AppServer`, although I think that could be one way to implement this (send http request to web service which writes the errors to database). Is there any lightweight way to invoke `AppServer` directly from the `Progress client` to do this?